# Perl - simple calculator that bends the rules of maths

Tags: function, perl, math, calculator

I'm trying to develop a simple calculator that bends the rules of math. I want it to ignore the usual math rules and perform from right to left. The user inputs a whole string as a math problem.
For example:

input: 123 - 10 + 4 * 10

Should be solved like this:

123 - 10 + 4 * 10 = 123 - ( 10 + ( 4 * 10 ) ) = 73.

Here is what i currently have:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {                                     # while we get input
my ($main, @ops) = reverse /[\d+\-*\/]+/g;   # extract the ops
while (@ops) {                               # while the list is not empty
    $main = calc($main, splice @ops, 0, 2);  # take 2 items off the list and process
}
say $main;                                   # print result
}

sub calc {
my %proc = (
    "+" => sub { $_[0] + $_[1] },
    "-" => sub { $_[0] - $_[1] },
    "/" => sub { $_[0] / $_[1] },
    "*" => sub { $_[0] * $_[1] }
);
return $proc{$_[1]}($_[0], $_[2]);
}
```

Here is what output i get:
123 - 10 + 4 * 10 = ((123 - 10) + 4) * 10 = 1170

As you can see - it solves the problem from left to right. My question is - how can i reverse this? I want it to get solved from right to left. Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Actually, your code does return -73 with the input you give

Comment: Your question is based on a false premise. The calculations are done right to left, but the operations are also reversed. You get `-73` when you should get `73`. I fixed that in my answer

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @tokens = @ARGV ? @ARGV : split /\s+/, '123 - 10 + 4 * 10';

if (grep { !/^[-+*i%]$/ and /\D/ } @tokens) {
  die "Invalid input: @tokens\n";
}

while (@tokens >= 3) {
  my $expr = join ' ', @tokens[-3 .. -1];

  splice @tokens, -3, 3, eval $expr;
}

say "@tokens";
```

I split the input into tokens and then process the array of tokens three elements at a time, working from the end. Each time, I replace the final three tokens with the result of evaluating the expression.

I've used `eval` here instead of the dispatch table calculator that you've used. You always want to be pretty sure of your input when using `eval`, so I've included a quick and dirty validation step as well.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a page from postfix/RPN evaluation strategies, and keeping two stacks, one for operations, one for numbers, makes for a simple implementation:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

{
    my %proc = (
        "+" => sub { $_[0] + $_[1] },
        "-" => sub { $_[0] - $_[1] },
        "/" => sub { $_[0] / $_[1] },
        "*" => sub { $_[0] * $_[1] }
        );

    sub calc {
        my @tokens = reverse split ' ', $_[0];
        my @opstack = grep { m!^[+-/*]$! } @tokens;
        my @numstack = grep { $_ !~ m!^[+-/*]$! } @tokens;

        for my $op (@opstack) {
            splice @numstack, 0, 2, $proc{$op}->(@numstack[1,0]);
        }
        return $numstack[0];
    }
}

say calc("123 - 10 + 4 * 10");
```

A more robust version would enforce an operator between every pair of numbers and have other error/sanity checking, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using the most amusing parts of Perl ?

This works and will return 73 if you enter the given test-case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

while (<>) {                                     # while we get input
chomp;s/ //g;
1 while s/\d+[+\-*\/]\d+$/$&/ee;
say;                                         # print result
}
```

If you want to understand how it works, just replace the no-op "1" to some STDERR output :

```
while (<>) {
chomp;s/ //g;
print STDERR "eval'd ($&) -> $_" while s/\d+[+\-*\/]\d+$/$&/ee;
say;
}
```

```
> ./test.pl
123 - 10 + 4 * 10
eval'd (4*10) -> 123-10+40
eval'd (10+40) -> 123-50
eval'd (123-50) -> 73
73
```

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64834196/725418) to your previous question, I said you could reverse the calculation by using `reverse`, and I see you have implemented that code.

As you have noticed, I assume, this is not true, because it would also invert the operations. I.e. `123 - 50` would become `50 - 123`. I was a little careless in that comment. You can however achieve the same effect if you just restore the order of the operands in the `calc()` call with another use of `reverse`.

```
$main = calc(reverse($main, splice @ops, 0, 2));  # take 2 items off the list and process
```

That would mean that your string `123 - 10 + 4 * 10` would first become a list

```
10 * 4 + 10 - 123
```

And then it would be called

```
calc(4, '*', 10)    # 40
calc(10, '+', 40)   # 50
calc(123, '-', 50)  # 73
```